# How to fix this error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in demoWcfService.DLL"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf

I have create a wcf service and consume it from an web application. I have define all the database connectivity in WCF and call from web applictaion.***Its showing the error at I Service1.cs in this page it showing the error An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in demoWcfService.DLL"  at this point "public string mobile"***

**IService1.cs:**

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string insertuserdetails(userdetails userinfo);
}

[DataContract]
public class userdetails
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name
    {
       get { return name; }
       set { name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string password
    {
       get { return password; }
       set { password = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string mobile
    {
       get { return mobile; }
       set { mobile = value; }
    }
}
```

**Service1.svc.cs:**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string insertuserdetails(userdetails userinfo)
    {
        string message;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(" Data Source=72.18.355.116,1533;Initial    
        Catalog=trainingcyber;User Id=cyber13;Password=train13cyber$$;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into info (name,password,mobile) 
       values(@name,@password,@mobile) ");

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", userinfo.name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", userinfo.password);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", userinfo.mobile);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            message = userinfo.name + " inforamation inserted ";
        }
        else
        {
            message = userinfo.name + "not inserted";
        }

        con.Close();
        return message;


    }
```

**Web Application Code: Default.aspx.cs:**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   ServiceReference1.Service1Client objServiceClientobjService = new    ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }

   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      userdetails userinfo = new userdetails();
      userinfo.name = TextBoxUserName.Text;
      userinfo.password = TextBoxPassword.Text;
      userinfo.mobile = TextBoxMobile.Text;

      string result = objServiceClientobjService.insertuserdetails(userinfo);
      LabelMessage.Text = result;


   }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact exception message? I do not see any reason why this piece of code should throw a StackOverflowException. Please include stack trace.

Comment: It showing following error so please solve this issue "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in demoWcfService.DLL"

Comment: please anyone send me the solution of this exception please..

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing your connection string in sqlCommand, i have change your method.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string insertuserdetails(userdetails userinfo)
    {
        string message;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(" Data Source=72.18.355.116,1533;Initial    
        Catalog=trainingcyber;User Id=cyber13;Password=train13cyber$$;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into info (name,password,mobile) 
       values(@name,@password,@mobile) ",con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", userinfo.name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", userinfo.password);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", userinfo.mobile);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            message = userinfo.name + " inforamation inserted ";
        }
        else
        {
            message = userinfo.name + "not inserted";
        }

        con.Close();
        return message;


    }
```